# Появления блока по нажатию при выполнении условия

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо чтобы при нажатии на блок в котором находится другой блок с определенным числовым значением появлялось модальное окно, а в нем скрытый блок. Вот код, в чем ошибка? Заранее спасибо.

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
    if (.child() == '5') {
        $('.modal').fadeIn();
        $('.hiddenblock').css('display', 'block');     
        }       
    });
```

Comment: Что такое `.child()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('.child').text() == 5){
        $('.modal').fadeIn();
        $('.hiddenblock').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, но только после text нужны еще видимо скобки ()

if($(this).find('.child').text() == 5)

Только столкнулся сразу еще с небольшой проблемой, видимо из-за того, что у меня все содержимое блока .parent создается скриптом, то после закрытия модального окна .hiddenblock веб-страница становится некликабельной, пока не сделаешь один клик в любом месте. Это как-нибудь возможно поправить?

Comment: Да, точно, пропустил скобки. Проблема связана с тем, что события при загрузке назначаются на существующие элементы. Если элементы создаются динамически, то вешается слушатель на весь документ с указанием нужного элемента.
`$(document).on("click",".parent",function(){//код});`

Comment: Прописал, не вышло, все так же